# Value in a union nested in a struct not updating

Tags: c, struct, unions

I'm writing a Stack implementation in C that allows for storing any data type. I have this so far:

```
// stack.h
enum ELEMENT_TYPE {
    ELEMENT_CHAR,
    ELEMENT_INT,
    ELEMENT_DOUBLE,
    ELEMENT_FLOAT
};

typedef struct {
    enum ELEMENT_TYPE type;
    union {
        char val_c;
        int val_i;
        double val_d;
        float val_f;
    };
} Stack_Element;

typedef struct {
    unsigned top;
    unsigned capacity;
    Stack_Element* elements;
} Stack;
```

```
Stack* stack_malloc(unsigned capacity) {
    Stack* stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->top = 0;
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->elements = (Stack_Element*)malloc(sizeof(stack->elements) * capacity);
    return stack;
}

void stack_push(Stack* stack, enum ELEMENT_TYPE type, ...) {
    if (isFull(stack)) {
        return;
    }

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, type);

    switch(type) {
        case ELEMENT_CHAR:
            printf("Pushing char: %c\n", (char) va_arg(ap, int));
            stack->elements[stack->top].val_c = (char) va_arg(ap, int); // issue
            printf("After pushing: %c\n", stack->elements[stack->top].val_c);
            break;
        case ELEMENT_INT:
            printf("Pushing int: %d\n", va_arg(ap, int));
            stack->elements[stack->top].val_i = va_arg(ap, int); // issue
            printf("After pushing: %d\n", stack->elements[stack->top].val_i);
            break;
        case ELEMENT_DOUBLE:
            printf("Pushing double: %f\n", va_arg(ap, double));
            stack->elements[stack->top].val_d = va_arg(ap, double); // issue
            printf("After pushing: %f\n", stack->elements[stack->top].val_d);
            break;
        case ELEMENT_FLOAT:
            printf("Pushing float: %f\n", (float) va_arg(ap, double));
            stack->elements[stack->top].val_f = (float) va_arg(ap, double); // issue
            printf("After pushing: %f\n", stack->elements[stack->top].val_f);
            break;
    }

    stack->elements[stack->top].type = type;
    stack->top++;
    va_end(ap);
}
```

The issue I'm having is in the line `stack->elements[stack->top].val_?`. In the first `printf`, where I print `Pushing X: %x`, the value is correct, so I'll have something like `Pushing int: 123`.

But then the output for the second `printf` is `After pushing: 291176586`, or another garbage value. I'm confused as to why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(stack->elements) * capacity)` is allocationg the wrong  size.  To avoid this sort of error, use the pattern `p = malloc(sizeof *p * N)`

Comment: Changed to `malloc(sizeof *stack->elements * capacity)` but it doesn't work. Also tried `sizeof stack->elements * capacity`

Comment: @Sami Use `stack->elements = malloc( capacity * sizeof *stack->elements);`

Comment: Use the correct version , don't "try things" - C is not a trial and error language

Comment: @4386427 what's the difference? `sizeof` has higher precedence than multiplication.

Comment: @DavidRanieri It wasn't the order that was important. It was because OPs comment showed that OP wasn't clear about whether it was `sizeof *stack->elements` or `sizeof stack->elements`. The order part is just a habbit of mine.

Comment: @4386427 ah ... ok, I thought you suggested changing the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `va_arg` incorrectly. The man page says:

*Each invocation of va_arg() modifies ap so
that the values of successive arguments are returned in turn.*

but you access it twice. Change your code to:

```
        char tmp = (char) va_arg(ap, int);  // Save in tmp variable
        printf("Pushing char: %c\n", tmp);
        stack->elements[stack->top].val_c = tmp;
        printf("After pushing: %c\n", stack->elements[stack->top].val_c);
        break;
```

Besides that your `malloc` is wrong as it has been pointed out in comments.

```
stack->elements = (Stack_Element*)malloc(sizeof(stack->elements) * capacity);
```

shall be

```
stack->elements = malloc(sizeof(*stack->elements) * capacity);
                                ^
                                notice
```

That said I prefer the order

```
stack->elements = malloc(capacity * sizeof *stack->elements);
```

but it's doing the same.

Comment: Good catch! Maybe `va_fetch` would have been a more accurate name for `va_arg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
stack->elements = (Stack_Element*)malloc(sizeof(stack->elements) * capacity);
```

`malloc` is wrong, `stack->elements` is pointer which length is 4.
shall be

```
stack->elements = (Stack_Element*)malloc(sizeof(Stack_Element) * capacity);
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the other answer. Also: _is pointer which length is 4_. It depends, on my platform (64 bits) is 8.